# Virtualbox Fedora 35 video playback is slowed with distorted audio

Tags: fedora

I am running Fedora 35 inside Oracle VM. Whenever I play videos on Youtube or even watch local video files, the playback is slowed and the audio is low pitch and distorted. Is there anything I can change in the settings to resolve this?

Comment: What's "Oracle VM"? Never heard of it.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov https://www.virtualbox.org/

Comment: You could try a different audio codec, i.e. AC'97.